# How do I serve specific and/or arbitrary static files from Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building an extension to a SASS product. This extension requires:

1. The `/` directory to contain `index.html`
2. The `/` directory to contain `config.json`
3. The `/` directory to contain `customActivity.js`
4. The `/` directory to contain `icon.png`

I'd like to keep my `config.json` and `customActivity.js` files in my projects `static` directory, and my `icon.png` file in the `media` directory. My `index.html` file should be via a template.

So far, my `urls.py` file looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

and my `views.py` looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("some stuff") // just an example
```

How do write a url paths that will direct `/` to the index view, but `/somefile.someextension` to either the `static` or `media` directories?